# Multithreading - Add point to series in VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading, charts, series

Good day

A chart has a set of 3 series added in the form:

```
(chrtReadTimePlot is private)
chrtRealTimePlot.Series.Add(SerRT_B_Voltage)
chrtRealTimePlot.Series.Add(SerRT_Charge_Current)
chrtRealTimePlot.Series.Add(SerRT_P_Voltage)
```

each series has its `get set` methods

**Problem**: Each series has data points added based on a Threading.Timer.Tick():

```
SerRT_B_Voltage.Points.AddXY(MPPTdata(x1,y1)
SerRT_Charge_Current.Points.AddXY(x2,y2)
SerRT_P_Voltage.Points.AddXY(MPPTdata(x3,y)
```

When adding a point to one of these series, I get a Cross-Thread error.

**Error:**

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control
>   'chrtRealTimePlot' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was
>   created on.

*I do not see how I can use a Invoke in this case*

Any thoughts/suggestions would be of immense help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cant comment because i dont have enough rating...

you must use delegates in order to safely update the GUI from another thread. read this: http://tech.xster.net/tips/invoke-ui-changes-across-threads-on-vb-net/

this article was very helpful to me when i was facing the same problem.